# Drawing a line on a UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to draw a line to indicate the current time on a scrollview (day planner).

I believe the issue is that the path is not valid because its taking the current views context and not the actual size of the scrollview content size.  If I make the currentTime float smaller value smaller it will draw a line.

```
float currentTime = ([components hour] * 60) + [components minute];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.scrollView.contentSize,NO,0.0);
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, currentTime, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, currentTime)];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [shapeLayer setFrame:self.scrollView.frame];
    [shapeLayer setPath:[path CGPath]];
    [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [shapeLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.scrollView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is not working the way you want it to.  Your code is drawing a rectangular path but you are asking about drawing a line.  You begin a drawing context, but then never use it.  You create a shapelayer with the scrollview frame instead of bounds.  There is a lot that doesn't make sense to me, but it could be correct depending on what you are trying to do.